# How can I test if my rotated rectangle intersects a corner?

Tags: collision-detection

I have a square, tile-based collision map. To check if one of my (square) entities is colliding, I get the vertices of the 4 corners, and test those 4 points against my collision map. If none of those points are intersecting, I know I'm good to move to the new position.

I'd like to allow entities to rotate. I can still calculate the 4 corners of the square, but once you factor in rotation, those 4 corners alone don't seem to be enough information to determine if the entity is trying to move to a valid state.

**For example:**

In the picture below, black is unwalkable terrain, and red is the player's hitbox. The left scenario is allowed because the 4 corners of the red square are not in the black terrain.

The right scenario would *also* be (incorrectly) allowed, because the player, cleverly turned at a 45* angle, has its corners in valid spaces, even if it is (quite literally) cutting the corner.

[image]

How can I detect scenarios similar to the situation on the right?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Separating Axis Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem)? Here's [an example complete with code](http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55).

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 Looks promising. I'd never heard of it before, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got a decent collision detection implemented. I wound up using a 3d version of [XenoCollide](http://xenocollide.snethen.com/) / Minkowski Portal Refinement, a la Gary Snethen in Game Programming Gems 7.

I've created a C# implementation of MPR below. It will return the direction of the minimum penetration vector. I know it's possible to return actual collision points, but I've not been able to implement that part, yet.

At any rate, here's the code for Minkowski Portal Refinement (MPR) / XenoCollide in 3d:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    //make the associated dot / cross products easier to read
    public static class Vector3Extensions
    {
        public static float Dot(this Vector3 op1, Vector3 op2)
        {
            return Vector3.Dot(op1, op2);
        }

        public static Vector3 Cross(this Vector3 op1, Vector3 op2)
        {
            return Vector3.Cross(op1, op2);
        }
    }

public static class MPRCollision {

    //points used by the algorithm
    static Vector3 v0;
    static Vector3 v1;
    static Vector3 v2;
    static Vector3 v3;
    static Vector3 v4;

    //if the difference in iteration is less than this,
    //we aren't going to (can't!) converge.
    static float kCollideEpsilon = 1e-3f;

    static Vector3 GetSupport(List<Vector3> shape, Vector3 direction)
    {


        Vector3 point = shape[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < shape.Count; i++)
        {
            //is the current point more "direction" than our result point?
            if ( (shape[i] - point).Dot(direction) > 0 )
            {
                //new result point
                point = shape[i];
            }
        }
        return point;

    }


    public static bool CheckCollide(List<Vector3> shape1, List<Vector3> shape2,
                                    Vector3 center1, Vector3 center2, ref Vector3 penVector)
    {
        //holding variables
        Vector3 n = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 swap = Vector3.zero;

        // v0 = center of Minkowski sum
        v0 = center2 - center1;

        // Avoid case where centers overlap -- any direction is fine in this case
        if (v0 == Vector3.zero) v0 = new Vector3(0, 0.00001f, 0);

        // v1 = support in direction of origin
        n = -v0;

        //get the differnce of the minkowski sum
        Vector3 v11 = GetSupport(shape1, -n);
        Vector3 v12 = GetSupport(shape2, n);

        v1 = v12 - v11;

        //if the support point is not in the direction of the origin
        if (v1.Dot(n) <= 0)
        {
            //return the direction of the origin, because we're not colliding
            if (penVector != null) penVector = n;
            return false;
        }

        // v2 - support perpendicular to v1,v0
        n = v1.Cross(v0);
        if (n == Vector3.zero)
        {
            //v1 and v0 are parallel, which means 
            //the origin is within the first portal?
            n = v1 - v0;

            if (penVector != null) penVector = n.normalized;
            return true;
        }

        //no early outs yet, so get the new support point
        Vector3 v21 = GetSupport(shape1, -n);
        Vector3 v22 = GetSupport(shape2, n);
        v2 = v22 - v21;

        if (v2.Dot(n) <= 0)
        {
            //can't reach the origin in this direction, ergo, no collision
            if (penVector != null) penVector = n;
            return false;
        }

        // Determine whether origin is on + or - side of plane (v1,v0,v2)
        //tests linesegments v0v1 and v0v2
        n = (v1 - v0).Cross(v2 - v0);
        float dist = n.Dot(v0);

        // If the origin is on the - side of the plane, reverse the direction of the plane
        if (dist > 0)
        {
            //swap the winding order of v1 and v2
            swap = v1;
            v1 = v2;
            v2 = swap;

            //swap the winding order of v11 and v12
            swap = v12;
            v12 = v11;
            v11 = swap;

            //swap the winding order of v11 and v12
            swap = v22;
            v22 = v21;
            v21 = swap;

            //and swap the plane normal
            n = -n;
        }


        ///
        // Phase One: Identify a portal

        while (true)
        {
            // Obtain the support point in a direction perpendicular to the existing plane
            // Note: This point is guaranteed to lie off the plane
            Vector3 v31 = GetSupport(shape1, -n);
            Vector3 v32 = GetSupport(shape2, n); 
            v3 = v32 - v31;

            if (v3.Dot(n) <= 0)
            {
                //can't enclose the origin within our tetrahedron
                if (penVector != null) penVector = n;
                return false;
            }

            // If origin is outside (v1,v0,v3), then eliminate v2 and loop
            if (v1.Cross(v3).Dot(v0) <= 0)
            {
                //failed to enclose the origin, adjust points;
                v2 = v3;
                v21 = v31;
                v22 = v32;
                n = (v1 - v0).Cross(v3 - v0);
                continue;
            }

            // If origin is outside (v3,v0,v2), then eliminate v1 and loop
            if (v3.Cross(v2).Dot(v0) < 0)
            {
                //failed to enclose the origin, adjust points;
                v1 = v3;
                v11 = v31;
                v12 = v32;
                n = (v3 - v0).Cross(v2 - v0);
                continue;
            }


            bool hit = false;

            ///
            // Phase Two: Refine the portal

            int phase2 = 0;

            // We are now inside of a wedge...
            while (phase2 < 20)
            {
                phase2++;

                // Compute normal of the wedge face
                n = (v2 - v1).Cross(v3 - v1);

                n.Normalize();

                // Compute distance from origin to wedge face
                float d = n.Dot(v1);

                // If the origin is inside the wedge, we have a hit
                if (d >= 0 && !hit )
                {
                    if (penVector != null) penVector = n;
                    hit = true;
                }


                // Find the support point in the direction of the wedge face
                Vector3 v41 = GetSupport(shape1, -n);
                Vector3 v42 = GetSupport(shape2, n);
                v4 = v42 - v41;


                float delta = (v4 - v3).Dot(n);
                float separation = -(v4.Dot(n));

                if (delta <= kCollideEpsilon || separation >= 0)
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Non-convergance detected");    
                    if (penVector != null) penVector = n;
                    return hit;
                }

                // Compute the tetrahedron dividing face (v4,v0,v1)
                float d1 = v4.Cross(v1).Dot(v0);

                // Compute the tetrahedron dividing face (v4,v0,v2)
                float d2 = v4.Cross(v2).Dot(v0);

                // Compute the tetrahedron dividing face (v4,v0,v3)
                float d3 = v4.Cross(v3).Dot(v0);

                if (d1 < 0)
                {
                    if (d2 < 0)
                    {
                        // Inside d1 & inside d2 ==> eliminate v1
                        v1 = v4;
                        v11 = v41;
                        v12 = v42;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Inside d1 & outside d2 ==> eliminate v3
                        v3 = v4;
                        v31 = v41;
                        v32 = v42;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (d3 < 0)
                    {
                        // Outside d1 & inside d3 ==> eliminate v2
                        v2 = v4;
                        v21 = v41;
                        v22 = v42;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Outside d1 & outside d3 ==> eliminate v1
                        v1 = v4;
                        v11 = v41;
                        v12 = v42;
                    }
                }
            }   

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 "I kind of fixed it, here's all my code" is a really unsatisfying answer. What did you change? What was the intuition behind your changes?

Comment: @Anko What are you referring to?

Comment: You had collision code. Then you changed something and to fix a problem with it, right? What did you change?

Comment: @Anko You mean my edit? I was missing an "=" in a "<=". This meant the code did not detect contact collisions in some cases.

Comment: No, I don't mean the edit. Sorry, I seem to be misunderstanding! I had the impression that when you asked the *question*, you had *version 1* of some collision detection code (but didn't post it) and when you wrote the *answer*, you had *version 2* (which you did post). In such a case, it would be useful to know what the changes were from version 1 (didn't work) to version 2 (did work). Do you mean to say that when asking the *question* you had no code at all and the code in the *answer* was written from scratch?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I had no collision code at all when I posted the question. Note the 2.5 week time difference between Question and Answer :P

Comment: I get it now. In that case, your code is properly helpful. I'd like to upvote instead, but apparently SE "locks in" downvotes unless the answer is edited. :/ I've put in a small clarifying edit for peer review and will fix my vote when that gets through. Thanks for explaining!